# samba, elastic beanstalk, and windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, samba

I have a deployed Elastic Beanstalk server on Amazon Linux.  I followed [this guide](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/linux-server-configuration-guide-book-excerpt,2-777-2.html) to add samba to it, using a similar configuration to one I have on an existing and working Ubuntu EC2.

Is there some reason why I can't seem to connect to the samba share from my windows server, using the public ip of the elastic beanstalk? It occurred to me that the elastic load balancer might be interfering.  Is this a thing?

Comment: what ports did you open on the ec2 security group?

Comment: I opened the server to all traffic from the windows servers ip

Comment: Wait.. do you use ELB for Samba? As far I know Samba uses 4 ports (TCP ports 139 and 445 and UDP ports 137 and 138) and that won't go through the load balancer. you can deploy the server through Beanstalk, but you  need to expose the server directly

Comment: A little more digging---I changed the password to the 'wrong password' and I got a 'username or password' message instead of the 'access denied' that I've been getting all along...must be a file permissions thing?

Comment: I fixed it, I needed to create the accessible directory inside the users home directory

Comment: that should be visible from the system logs. It is possible to 'autocreate' user's home directories so even user which was not known before could accesss the samba (usefull with AD)